# Unity Circle calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

for my programm im programming a "clock like" behaviour. Meaning i

- order some pictures in a circle (works)
- if i click and drag on any item all items should rotate with the mouse (works)

But i get a weird bug. The first time i click and hold the mouse my images "jump" to different positions. if i hold the mouse down i can rotate my clock ust fine.
When i MouseUp and start dragin from the same image it works well. if i go to another image i get this "Jump" again.

When i only have a few images on my clock i see that it doesnt jump. but the start position seems to bee off.
When i only have one item, i can rotate it in a circle, but the moment i start to rotate it jumps away from my mouse and than i can rotate it as desired.

For me it seems to be a wrong "starting point" when first dragging an item. SInce it works fine when i than drag the same item again and again.
Unfortunately i cant find the damn bug, and im searching the whole day already.

#

```
public void SetLayoutHorizontal ()
{
    Debug.Log ("LAYOUT");

    for (var i =0; i < Rect.childCount; i++)
    {
        var PanelPrefab = Rect.GetChild (i) as RectTransform;

        Transform ImageObject = PanelPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<Transform>().Find("Image");

        if (PanelPrefab == null)
            continue;

        PanelPrefab.sizeDelta = CellSize;
        PanelPrefab.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(radius * Mathf.Sin( CalculateCircleAngle(i) - deltaRadian),radius * Mathf.Cos(CalculateCircleAngle(i) - deltaRadian));

    }

}

private float CalculateCircleAngle(int parts)
{
    //parts == Number of parts the whole circle is to be cut into
    return parts * (360/Rect.childCount) * (Mathf.PI/180);
}

public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    var diffX = eventData.position.x - _rect.rect.width/2; // MouseX - CenterScreenX
    var diffY = eventData.position.y - _rect.rect.height/2; // MouseY - CenterScreenY
    deltaRadian = Mathf.Atan2(diffY,diffX);

    SetDirty();

}
```

Edit:

Ok i Edited the code but it still is not working.
I added the following method:

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    originalX = eventData.position.x;
    originalY = eventData.position.y;

}
```

and i changed the drag method acordingly

```
public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
{

    var diffX = eventData.position.x - originalX;
    var diffY = eventData.position.y - originalY;
    deltaRadian = Mathf.Atan2(diffY,diffX);

    SetDirty();

}
```

The "Jumping" at the beginning of my drag event is gone, but the speed of the draggin is not on par with my mouse.
The closer i am to my starting point of the drag, the faster it moves, the further away i am the slower it gets.
I dont know if this brought me closer to a solution or further away :(

Edit2:
Ok i think the problem might be that my calculations were all done from the center point of view as 0,0 point.
Unity has the bottom left point as 0,0. So i somehow have to translate all those coordiantes first...

Answer (score 1):

All that was needed was a transformation to kartesian coordinates

```
//Convert to kartesian coordinates with 0,0 in center of screen
    var diffX = (eventData.position.x - _rect.rect.width / 2) % (_rect.rect.width / 2);
    var diffY = (eventData.position.y - _rect.rect.height / 2) % (_rect.rect.height / 2);
```

and an addition of the delta instead of the subtraction

```
PanelPrefab.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(radius * Mathf.Sin(CalculateCircleAngle(i) + deltaRadian),radius * Mathf.Cos(CalculateCircleAngle(i) + deltaRadian));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse coordinates are relative to the control you click in. You could re-calculate them using the control's position within its container or you use absolute coordinates.

Comment: Any tips on how i can do that with my eventData.position?

Comment: @Hunselfunsel, Sorry, I have no current enviroment to test this out. What you could do: Print out the coordinates somewhere on the screen and try to **understand** what happens. Each control you click in has its own (0/0). Each control has a position stating its location within its parent. Just google something like "c# get mouse position" and you will get loads of hints ;-)

Comment: thx i got it. the position.x is already in world coordiantes. i just had to transform them into kartesian ones with 0/0 beeing in the center.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are displaying all the relevant code, but your OnDrag function, specifically diffX, and diffY probably provide the answer for you.

I believe you're taking the absolute coordinates of the location you pick, and using them to generate your angle - which means that almost anywhere you click is a big jump from however the current angle is set.  Your initial click handler should save off a starting coordinate, and your OnDrag should compare itself against that initial coordinate, based on how far you've dragged from that saved location.

Comment: I tried it like you said (see edit). Unfortunately i dont know if this braught me closer or further away from my goal :(

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your code locally, so I can see the problem.
Please provide the definitions for:
Rect, and _rect
Also, you may consider renaming your "Rect" variable because that's the name of a datatype in Unity.

Comment: Thx, i got it finally. all i had to do was transform the position data into kartesian coordiantes.